# How to access private variable in aspectj

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, aspectj

So I have a scenario where I want to access context variable in a RESTful web service that is written using jersey.

```
 @Path("hello")
 public class Hello {

 @Context
 private UriInfo context;

  @GET
  @Produces("text/html")
  public String getHtml(@Context Request request, @Context HttpServletRequest requestss)     {
    ...
    context.getBaseUri();
    ...
  }
```

In my aspect using `@Around` pointcut I can see that arguments are ARGS: `[org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.RequestInjectee@7d9d679,org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6e8fa5f5]`, so I can easily access Request object.

My aspect is as follows:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *.getHtml(..))")
public void methodCall() {}

@Around("methodCall()") 
public Object aroundMethodCall(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("AROUND" + pjp.getSignature());
    System.out.println("ARGS: "+ Arrays.toString(pjp.getArgs()));
    return pjp.proceed();
}
```

I would like to  access `context` variable in my aspect (to log it). In my aspect getThis() methods returns Hello class but the context field is private. Is it possible ? I am using load time weaving.

Comment: Can you add a public `getContext()` method to your Hello class? Otherwise, with Java 7 and up anyway, I'd look at [MethodHandle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch nope I cannot, the idea is to have not invasive logging for jersey apps (not written by me)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes java 7

Comment: Then you can use a [MethodHandle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the problem with MethodHandle is that I need to know the type and import it before using. In my scenario I will learn the type during the execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to do a few steps, assuming your `Object` reference is `obj` then you could try

```
Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("context");
field.setAccessible(true);
UriInfo context = (UriInfo) field.get(obj);
```